# Differences between 2 arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I have 2 arrays

- $cpe
- $sample

---

## $cpe array info

```
array:23 [▼
  "cpe_mac" => "298639133839"
  "bandwidth_max_up" => 30000
  "bandwidth_max_down" => 50000
  "filter_icmp_inbound" => true
  "dmz_enabled" => false
  "dmz_host" => "http:\/\/ddd.com"
  "vlan_id" => 2
  "dns" => array:2 [▶]
  "xdns_mode" => 0
  "cfprofileid" => 11111
  "stub_response" => "0"
  "acl_mode" => 1
  "portal_url" => "http:\/\/portal.com"
  "fullbandwidth_max_up" => 1000000
  "fullbandwidth_max_down" => 2000000
  "fullbandwidth_guaranty_up" => 300000
  "fullbandwidth_guaranty_down" => 400000
  "account_id" => 1000
  "location_id" => 3333
  "network_count" => 3
  "group_name" => "test_group"
  "vse_id" => 20
  "firewall_enabled" => false
]
```

---

## $sample array info

```
array:23 [▼
  "cpe_mac" => "a0a1a2a3a4a5"
  "bandwidth_max_up" => 300000
  "bandwidth_max_down" => 500000
  "filter_icmp_inbound" => true
  "dmz_enabled" => false
  "dmz_host" => "http] = \/\/ddd.com"
  "vlan_id" => 2
  "dns" => array:2 [▶]
  "xdns_mode" => 0
  "cfprofileid" => 11111
  "stub_response" => ""
  "acl_mode" => 1
  "portal_url" => "http] = \/\/portal.com"
  "fullbandwidth_max_up" => 1000000
  "fullbandwidth_max_down" => 2000000
  "fullbandwidth_guaranty_up" => 300000
  "fullbandwidth_guaranty_down" => 400000
  "account_id" => 1234
  "location_id" => 3333
  "network_count" => 3
  "group_name" => "test_group"
  "vse_id" => 20
  "firewall_enabled" => false
]
```

---

I look through them countless time with my eyes, they look the same to me **except** their value. Then, I compare them programmatically,

```
$equal = ($cpe == $sample );
dd($equal); // false
```

I think, it return `false` because their values is different. Am I right ?

---

How do I check if those array have the same

- `length`
- `key`
- `data-type`

If **different**, how can I find out what is it exactly that make them different ?

Comment: I can probably guarantee it's not happening on those lines, but on a line where you go to echo `$result`, or call another function that requires a string

Comment: @iam-decoder Actually that's not true. [I can guarantee that these arrays in `array_diff` will cause this warning in PHP 5.4.0+](https://3v4l.org/Ir5ID)[The manual indicates that `array_diff`](http://php.net/array-diff) compares values as strings such that `if ((string) $elem1 === (string) $elem2)` then they are equal. So if you have a multi-dimensional array, as is here, you get `Array to string conversion`

Comment: @Sherif good to know, I've never done a diff on a MDArray. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how you believe that these arrays can be equal. They're clearly not.

For example `$sample["cpe_mac"] == "a0a1a2a3a4a5"` and `$cpe["cpe_mac"] == "298639133839"`. Also `$sample["bandwidth_max_up"] == 300000` and `$cpe["bandwidth_max_up"] ==  30000`. Just by looking at the array you can immediately tell they aren't equal so there's no logical reason to believe that `$cpe == $sample` should ever be `true`.

[Also `array_diff` compares values as strings](http://php.net/array-diff). What you have is a multi-dimensional array. So it is not possible to compute the differences of non-scalar elements  in the array with `array_diff`.

> #### Note:
>
> This function **only checks one dimension** of a n-dimensional array. Of course you can check deeper dimensions by using `array_diff($array1[0], $array2[0]);`.

Also a second note the manual elaborates...

> #### Note:
>
> Two elements are considered equal if and only `if (string) $elem1 === (string) $elem2`. In words: when the string representation is the same.

---

To compute the the non equal elements between the two arrays you may need to iterate over them and compare one element at a time.

### Example

```
$diff = [];

foreach($cpe as $key => $value) {
    if (array_key_exists($key, $sample) && $sample[$key] !== $value) {
        $diff[$key] = $sample[$key];
    }
}
```

You could also write this as a recursive function to compute differences within n-dimensional arrays...

```
function array_diff_recursive(Array $a, Array $b, Array $diff = [])
{
    foreach($a as $k => $v) {
        if (!array_key_exists($k, $b)) {
            $diff[$k] = $v;
            continue;
        }
        if (is_array($v)) {
            $diff += array_diff_recursive($v, $b[$k], $diff);
        } else {
            if ($v !== $b[$k]) { // you could change this to == for loose comparison
                $diff[$k] = $v;
            }
        }
    }
    return $diff;
}
```

Comment: I said **except** their  value.

Comment: Right, but in PHP an array is made up of **ordered** key/value pairs. So when comparing two arrays in PHP they must both have identically ordered key/value pairs. You can check the [truth table](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php) for reference as well and look at the [type comparison](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php) in the manual for arrays where it clearly states `**TRUE** if $a and $b have the same key/value pairs.`.

Comment: I'm just stressing that there should be no expectation that two arrays can be equal in PHP just because they have the same keys or because they have same values alone. Both key and value are compared as a *pair*.

Answer (score 0):

array_diff require the first parameter **An array to compare from** and **second parameter An array to compare against** and will **return an array containing the entries from Array to compare from**  that are not present in any of the other arrays

```
   $arr1 = array('first', 'second', 'third');
   $arr2 = array('first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth', 'fifth');
   print_r(array_diff($arr2, $arr1)); //Array ( [3] => fourth [4] => fifth )
```

but if you change the array places

```
 $arr1 = array('first', 'second', 'third');
 $arr2 = array('first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth', 'fifth');
 print_r(array_diff($arr1, $arr2)); //Array ( )
```

Answer (score 0):

I would compare the array's key by this..

```
if (empty(array_diff_key($arr, $sample) ) ) {
    echo "they have the same key";
}
```

Although I should mention `55` is the same as `"55"`, but this only apply an array's key that is an integer